# Vue Typeerror Method is not a funcion?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, frontend

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
        at eval (Auth.vue?7df1:27)
```

Here is my error.

The linter isnt giving any errors and i cant see any errors.
Devtools say method is an object type and thus not callable as a function.

Really not sure whats going on here.

```
      methods: {
        submitForm: () => {
          this.login(this.userData)
            .then((response) => {
              // eslint-disable-next-line
              console.log(response);
              this.$router.push('/');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              // eslint-disable-next-line
              console.log(error);
            });
        },
        ...mapActions(['login']),
```

Comment: I doubt `this` is going to work with the arrow function, you'll probably need to declare it using the usual `function`

Comment: So I've narrowed the error down to `...mapActions` behind inside `the method` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is an object, `submitForm:`, which contains an anonymous function `() => {...}`, but still, it is an object.

Go for `submitForm() { ... }` as the shorthand. That expands into `submitForm: function () {}` whereas what you have remains an anon function inside an object, thus giving you the error.

Comment: Just changed it but its throwing the same error. Thats how i originally had the code and it gave this error which surprised me because i was sure this was correct.